# How to get open positions or close them - Interactive Brokers API

Tags: c#, interactive-brokers

Created shared delegate.

```
class Delegation
{
  public delegate void IBError(Exception e);
  public static IBError Error;

  public delegate void IBNextId(int orderId);
  public static IBNextId NextId;

  public delegate void IBMessage(string message);
  public static IBMessage Message;
}
```

Implemented wrapper for IB API.

```
public class IBWrapper : EWrapper
{
  // ... some other handlers go here

  public virtual void error(Exception e)
  {
    Delegation.Error(e);
    Delegation.Message("ERROR: " + e.Message);
  }

  public virtual void tickPrice(int tickerId, int field, double price, int canAutoExecute)
  {
    Delegation.Message("TICK PRICE");
  }

  public virtual void position(string account, Contract contract, double pos, double avgCost)
  {
    Delegation.Message("POSITION");
  }
}
```

Then use it.

```
public class Broker
{
  public static string apiHost = "127.0.0.1";
  public static int apiPort = 7496;

  public static int Main(string[] args)
  {
    var api = new IBWrapper();
    var client = CreateSocket(api);
    var channel = new ChannelService();

    Delegation.Error += (e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); };
    Delegation.Message += (message) => 
    {
        // This method should intercept ALL messages from IB API
        // but it does not work for positions 
        Console.WriteLine(message); 
    };
    Delegation.NextId += (orderId) => {

        var action = "CLOSE"; // This variable comes from external app

        if (action == "CLOSE")
        {
          // Option #2: subscribe to messages from IB before some action

          client.reqIds(-1);
          client.reqAllOpenOrders();
          client.reqAutoOpenOrders(true);
          client.reqOpenOrders();
          client.reqPositions();
          client.reqAccountUpdates(true, "XXXXXXXXX");

          //CancelOrders(client);
          ClosePositions(client);
          return;
        }

        order.Id = orderId;
        //SendOrder(socket, order);
        //SendCurrencyOrder(client, order);

      client.eDisconnect();
    };

    // Option #1: try to subscribe to messages from IB at the start

    client.reqIds(-1);
    client.reqAllOpenOrders();
    client.reqAutoOpenOrders(true);
    client.reqOpenOrders();
    client.reqPositions();
    client.reqAccountUpdates(true, "XXXXXXXXX");

    Console.ReadKey();
    return 0;
  }
}
```

**Question:** how to get list of open positions and close them?

In some reason I can get message from IB API when I receive "NextOrderId", "OpenOrder", but cannot get notifications about account data and open positions...

**Description from IB API docs:** API programs always have at least two threads of execution. One thread is used for sending messages to TWS, and another thread is used for reading returned messages. The second thread uses the API EReader class to read from the socket and add messages to a queue. Everytime a new message is added to the message queue, a notification flag is triggered to let other threads now that there is a message waiting to be processed. In the two-thread design of an API program, the message queue is also processed by the first thread. In a three-thread design, an additional thread is created to perform this task. The thread responsible for the message queue will decode messages and invoke the appropriate functions in EWrapper.

https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/connection.html#ereader

Comment: what happens inside `client.reqPositions();`

Comment: @zaitsman internally it's writing to some socket stream (BinaryWriter tcpWriter).Write(msg), it should notify TWS app about my request for positions and TWS should send me a response, I added description of the architecture used by IB

Comment: On connection you get nextOrderID and some other stuff without asking, you should be getting "errors" as well, but they're really notifications saying you're connected.  You  don't show all of the wrapper implementation so I'll assume it's correct.  In TWS you should enable api logging so you can see what you're actually sending and receiving.